# ` No route matches` error for Nested Resources Controller Spec - Rails, Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, nested-routes

I keep getting `No route matches` error for a nested resource `#create` action. Here is what I got:

**routes:**

```
...
resources :users, only: [:show, :create] do 
  resources :filters, only: [:new,:create]
end
...
```

**controller spec:**

```
...
context 'with valid attributes' do 
  it "creates new Filter" do
    expect{
    post :create, {:filter => attributes_for(:filter)}
    }.to change(Filter, :count).by(1)
  end
...
```

**error:**

```
No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"filters", :filter=>{[long filter hash]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is nested, you also need to include the ID for the parent object that the filter will belong to.

```
post :create, user_id: <some_user_id>, {:filter => attributes_for(:filter)}
```

Comment: `unexpected keyword_end, expecting '}'` syntax error. I tried passing user  id in the options hash like this: `post :create, {:filter => attributes_for(:filter), :user_id => 1}`, and got a different error: `undefined method "filters" for "1":String`

Comment: That is true.  Using multiple hash types tends to confuse ruby.

Something like this would probably do better.
`post :create, user_id: u, filter: attributes_for(:filter)`

Comment: same thing. `user_id: u` returns `undefined method / variable "u"`. I tried declaring user id through an instance variable `@user`, `:post :create, user_id: @user.id, filter: attributes_for(:filter)`  and got the routing error again.